# Which part of the HTML specification cause a URL within angle-brackets to be parsed as an <http:> element with attributes?

Tags: html, url, standards, specifications

Here is my HTML code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<head>
    <title>Bar</title>
    <script>
    window.onload = function() {
        console.log(document.body.innerHTML)
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<http://www.example.com/foo/bar/baz.html>
</body>
</html>
```

I save this code in a file named `bar.html` and then open the page with Firefox or Chrome. This is the output I see in the console.

```
<http: www.example.com="" foo="" bar="" baz.html="">


</http:>
```

Now I understand that my code was incorrect because it had a URL enclosed within `<` and `>`.

I want to understand how exactly did the browser parse it as an `http:` tag with parts of the URL interpreted as HTML attributes.

Is there some part of the HTML specification that leads to this kind of behavior? If so, could you please quote such parts of the HTML specification?

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/syntax.html#parsing-html-documents

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything you need to know is in [section 8.2.4](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#tokenization). In particular:

1. Up to `<http:`, the parser is in the [tag name state](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#tag-name-state). The element's tag name is `http:`, including the colon, as evidenced by the `</http:>` end tag.
2. The first `/` switches the parser to the [self-closing start tag state](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#self-closing-start-tag-state).
3. The *second* `/` causes a parse error as described in the link in step 2, switching the parser to the [before attribute name state](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#before-attribute-name-state).
4. The parser enters the [attribute name state](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#attribute-name-state) and continues consuming the URL. This is what causes paths of the path to be treated as attribute names.
5. When the parser reaches the next `/`, it switches back to the self-closing start tag state and repeats steps 2 and 3, except that it's not a second `/` but a different character (that isn't `>`) that causes the parse error and switches the parser back to the before attribute name state in step 3.
6. Once the parser finally sees a `>`, it closes the start tag, emits it, and proceeds as normal.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Do you know why these parsing rules don't work within a `<textarea></textarea>` element. Within a `<textarea></textarea>` element, I see that `<http://www.example.com/foo/bar/baz.html>` is preserved intact. Which part of the spec covers this behavior?

Comment: @LoneLearner - From the same section that BoltClock's quoting from, when the textarea element is seen, the parser insertion mode is switched to ["text"](http://w3c.github.io/html/syntax.html#in-text) instead of "in body" (as it would be in your question's example, there are other modes it could also be) and the parsing rules are different.

Answer (score -3):

HTML specification defines HTML concept, but not how to parse it, as far as I know. Parsing algorithm is internal subject of browser's programmers and they do their best to parse HTML with errors even.

Comment: The parsing algorithm is public and forms part of the HTML5 spec. See BoltClock's answer.